# Are Pure, Presentational and Dumb Components all the same thing?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Are Pure, Presentational and Dumb Components all the same thing?

Basically, stateless functional components, which are concern about How Look and not How Work, and are never connected to Redux store?

Comment: Only containers should be connected. Presentational component doesn't mean it's stateless, it just means it doesn't alter the global state. A button could have a state (clicked, not clicked, disabled, blah blah) and still be a presentational component. You can have stateful functional components with hooks now.

Comment: Is a Pure Component the same as a stateless functional component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a fundamental level, any function that doesn’t alter input data and that doesn’t depend on external state (like a database, DOM, or global variable) and consistently provides the same output for the same input is a **pure** functions

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b //pure function
```

In React, a **presentational component** or a **dumb component** is a component that just renders HTML. Their only responsibility is to present something to the DOM.These components are often just Javascript functions. They don’t have internal state to manage. They wouldn’t know how to change the data they are presenting if they were asked. Ignorance is bliss.
In a Redux-powered app, **such components do not interact with the Redux store.**

However, they accept props from a **container component** (**smart components**). 
Class-based components that have their own state defined in their constructor() functions

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {pictures : []};
  }
}
```

Because container components have the burden of being smart, they are the ones that keep track of state and care about how the app works. They also specify the **data and behavior** a presentational components should render by passing it down to them as props.If the presentational component has any interactivity — like a button — it calls a prop-function given to it by the container component. But **the container component is the one to dispatch an action to the Redux store.**